# How do I interleave rows from two data frames by key/value?

Tags: r

I would like to combine data from two tables by interleaving them based on time stamp.  Because the "Box" column has multiple values they are of unequal length.

```
DateTime    Box TempIn
10/10/2017 4:00 B1  5
10/10/2017 4:00 B2  5
10/10/2017 4:00 B3  5
10/10/2017 5:00 B1  5
10/10/2017 5:00 B2  5
10/10/2017 5:00 B3  5

DateTime    TempOut
10/10/2017 4:00 22
10/10/2017 5:00 22
```

My goal is to interleave the "Temp*" columns so the final table looks like this:

```
DateTime    Box Temp
10/10/2017 4:00 B1  5
10/10/2017 4:00 B2  5
10/10/2017 4:00 B3  5
10/10/2017 4:00 Ext 22
10/10/2017 5:00 B1  5
10/10/2017 5:00 B2  5
10/10/2017 5:00 B3  5
10/10/2017 5:00 Ext 22
```

Any advice?  Using TidyR I can get this far but my dates are out of order.

```
spread(df, Box, TempIn)

         DateTime B1 B2 B3
1 10/10/2017 4:00  5  5  5
2 10/10/2017 5:00  5  5  5

df$Ext <- df2$TempOut

         DateTime B1 B2 B3 Ext
1 10/10/2017 4:00  5  5  5  22
2 10/10/2017 5:00  5  5  5  22


df %>% gather(Box, Temp, -DateTime)
         DateTime Box Temp
1 10/10/2017 4:00  B1    5
2 10/10/2017 5:00  B1    5
3 10/10/2017 4:00  B2    5
4 10/10/2017 5:00  B2    5
5 10/10/2017 4:00  B3    5
6 10/10/2017 5:00  B3    5
7 10/10/2017 4:00 Ext   22
8 10/10/2017 5:00 Ext   22
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some efforts and a yielding specific coding issue. A look into `?merge()` might help.

Comment: I've tried to use tidyr to spread(Box, Temp), add my column, then gather() but because there are multiple time points I get a data frame of the same number of rows where each "Box" still has one temp value but NAs in all others.

Comment: Alternatively, since I am plotting these, I can plot a second geom_line() with ggplot so they are both on the same chart, but I would like to learn how to merge them.

Comment: That's good. Just edit your question with these details, rather there as here in comments after been asked. I'm sure you have read, how to ask a great question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Done, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the larger data frame is called `df` and the other one is called `df2`

```
# Rename to prepare for rbind
names(df) <- ifelse(names(df) == 'TempIn', 'Temp', names(df))
names(df2) <- ifelse(names(df2) == 'TempOut', 'Temp', names(df))
# Add box to df2
df2$Box <- 'Ext'

# Split each by DateTime, rbind each of the splits, then rbind everything
do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, split(df, df$DateTime), split(df2, df2$DateTime)))

#           DateTime Box Temp
# 1: 10/10/2017 4:00  B1    5
# 2: 10/10/2017 4:00  B2    5
# 3: 10/10/2017 4:00  B3    5
# 4: 10/10/2017 4:00 Ext   22
# 5: 10/10/2017 5:00  B1    5
# 6: 10/10/2017 5:00  B2    5
# 7: 10/10/2017 5:00  B3    5
# 8: 10/10/2017 5:00 Ext   22
```

These all gives the same result

```
do.call(rbind, rbind(split(df, df$DateTime), split(df2, df2$DateTime)))

##################################

library(tidyverse)

list(df, df2) %>% 
  map(~split(.x, .x$DateTime)) %>% 
  do.call(what = rbind) %>% 
  do.call(what = rbind)

##################################

list(df, df2) %>% 
  map(~split(.x, .x$DateTime)) %>%
  flatten %>% 
  .[order(names(.))] %>% 
  bind_rows
```